# SetInterval script applied to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script fills several tables with ajax queries if they are active, and cleans the inactive tables:

```
        $(".my_button_tables").on("click", function(event) {
            var thetable = $(event.target).parent().next("table");
            if (thetable.prop('rows').length)    thetable.empty(); 
            else {    
                fill_ajax($("#id_study").val(), thetable); // Fill the table
            };
        });
```

I want to reload the active ajax queries every X seconds. I'm using setInterval but I have problems with the code. Any solution?

Comment: What problems do you have? What currently happens? Are you able to post an example structure of the page? How/where does the `setInterval` call occur (it isn't in your code there...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my inspiration came after asking the question. Before I was using setInterval inside the onclick function. Now I found a solution simply adding another script:

```
        var table_refresher = setInterval( function() {
            $(".my_button_tables").parent().next("table").each(function(){
                if ($(this).prop('rows').length)    fill_ajax($("#id_study").val(), $(this)); // Fill the table    
            });
        }, 15000);
```